# Comparing things in Python using type cast

Tags: python

```py
>>> print(type(float)==type(str))
True
```

Why is it true?

Comment: Because both `float` and `str` are types in Python, so both `type(float)` and `type(str)` result in `type` (the type of all type objects in Python).

Comment: It didn't occur to you to look at `type(float)` and `type(str)` and see what they are?

Comment: It's not clear where exactly you believe there is any type casting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function [type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) did the following task:

> With one argument, return the type of an object. The return value is a type object and generally the same object as returned by object.**class**.

`str` and `float` are [built-in data types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) of python. So your code works like this:

```py
print(type(str))   # <class 'type'>
print(type(float)) # <class 'type'>
```

If you want to get the desired result, you can use the following code:

```py
s = "test"
f = 3.0
print(type(s)==type(f)) # false
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because type(float) and type(str) are "type" objects

If you need to verify the type of a float value you can do something like this

```
float_value = 10.3
print(type(float_value) == float) # True
```

Another example with a string:

```
string_value = "hi"
print(type(string_value) == str) # True
```